# Eslint: component definition is missing display name for Combined Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I have a function that combines multiple context provider components and returns one combined Context Provider. I am getting an eslint error: `Component definition is missing display name (eslintreact/display-name)`. How can I resolve the error?

```js
const providers = [AuthProvider, CartProvider, LocationProvider];

const combineComponents = (...components: FC[]): FC => {
  return components.reduce(
    (AccumulatedComponents, CurrentComponent) => {
      return ({ children }: ComponentProps<FC>): JSX.Element => {
        return (
          <AccumulatedComponents>
            <CurrentComponent>{children}</CurrentComponent>
          </AccumulatedComponents>
        );
      };
    },
    ({ children }) => <>{children}</>
  );
};

export const CombinedContextProvider = combineComponents(...providers);
```

[image]

The `CombinedContextProvider` component can then be used in `App.tsx` in the following way:

```js
import React from 'react';

const App: React.FC = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  <CombinedContextProvider>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </CombinedContextProvider>
)};

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this help? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55620562/eslint-component-definition-is-missing-displayname-react-display-name

Comment: Thanks for the link, the code is very different in that question. It's difficult to draw a correlation.

Comment: The issue is the same which is that your component is an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a comment that mentioned the issue was an anonymous function, I was able to resolve the error with the following code:

```js
import React, { ComponentProps, FC } from 'react';

import { AuthProvider } from './auth_context';
import { CartProvider } from './cart_context';
import { LocationProvider } from './location_context';

const providers = [AuthProvider, CartProvider, LocationProvider];

const combineComponents = (...components: FC[]): FC => {
  return components.reduce(
    (AccumulatedComponents, CurrentComponent) => {
      return function AccumulateComponents({ children }: ComponentProps<FC>): JSX.Element {
        return (
          <AccumulatedComponents>
            <CurrentComponent>{children}</CurrentComponent>
          </AccumulatedComponents>
        );
      };
    },
    ({ children }) => <>{children}</>,
  );
};

export const CombinedContextProvider = combineComponents(...providers);
```